# Swift Segue Without adding / Creating stack

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller

I want to go to a View Controller I created in the story board without putting it on a stack. I have a Navigation bar already Inside of the view so I don't want to add another. So basically this new view that I segue to will be the Main view, so its the only view on the stack.

Button Action

```
@IBAction func addToPlanner(_ sender: Any) {
        let objSecondVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddToPlannerViewController") as? AddToPlannerViewController
        present(objSecondVc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your VC already had Navigation Controller use pushViewController

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddToPlannerViewController") as? AddToPlannerViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

Comment: I dont have a Navigation Controller I have a Navigation Bar added to the View Controller

Answer (score 0):

Inside if Button Action to remove top space area do

```
let objSecondVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddToPlannerViewController") as? AddToPlannerViewController
objSecondVc!.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(objSecondVc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```